# Dont find socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Files

```
chat
    node_modules
    web
       public
          css
             estilo.css
          img
             tiempo.jpg
          js
             script.js
          view
             vista.html
       app.js
       package.json
```

JSON

```
{
    "name":"chat",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "privte":"true",
    "dependencies":{
        "socket.io":"1.4.8",
        "express": "4.14.0"
    }   
}
```

In the File **vista.html** I can't open or load the soket.io, but I can load the files: pictures, css, js - don't have a problem with that. The problem is to try to load **soket.io**

NODE.js File, **app.js**

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    http = require("http").Server(app), 
    io = require("socket.io")(http), 
    nicknames=[],
    users={};


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('SERVIDOR LISTO');
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/web/public'));

app.get("/",function(req, res){
        res.sendFile( __dirname+'/web/public/view/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){ 
    .......
    .......
}
```

and my html file is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <img src="http://localhost:3000/img/tiempo.jpg" 
     alt="Smiley face" height="30%" width="30%">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I had to reorder the code, what starts first and finish with the last.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    io      = require('socket.io'),
    nicknames=[],
    users={}; 

var server=app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('SERVIDOR LISTO');
});

var mysocket  = io.listen(server);  
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/web/public'));

app.get("/",function(req, res){
        res.sendFile( __dirname+'/web/public/view/index.html');
});
```